# Multiple where clauses in rails searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, searchkick

I have a very basic question about searchkick. What if you want you join multiple where statements in searchkick query using if statements. Much like query-builder

```
    @product = Product.all

    unless request.end_date.nil?
        @product = @product.search, where('created_at <= ?', request.end_date)
    end 

    unless request.max_price.nil?
        @product = @product.search, where('price <= ?', request.max_price)
    end 

    @product
```

The above code works fine if request has either end date or max_price. If it has both, it throws an error. Is there a way to construct or concatenate the two where statements. I cannot do

```
Product.search '*', where('created_at <= ?', request.end_date), where('price <= ?', request.max_price)
```

because if statement is important.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should check docs of Searchkick, it has Or filter: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

```
where: {
  expires_at: {gt: Time.now}, # lt, gte, lte also available
  or: [
    [{in_stock: true}, {backordered: true}]
  ]
}
```

For your case, you can deal with it as below:

```
conditions[:or] = [[]]
unless request.end_date.nil?
    conditions[:or][0] += [{created_at: {lt: request.end_date}}]
end 

unless request.max_price.nil?
    conditions[:or][0] += [{price: {lt: request.max_price}}]
end 
Product.search '*', where: conditions
```